# PHP MySql Print decimal number

Tags: php, mysql, database, decimal

Here is my code:

DATABASE SETUP

```
<?php
$user="k*********";
$password="*********";
$database="**********";
mysql_connect("localhost",$user,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$query = "CREATE TABLE rn (
PID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(PID),
dait CHAR(10),
rnfl INT ,
)";
mysql_query($query);
mysql_close();
?>
```

database update

```
<?php
// Connect to MySQL
mysql_connect("localhost", "*********", "**************") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("********") or die(mysql_error());
$dait="31/7/2014";
$rnfl=12.9;
// Update  
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE rn SET dait='$dait', rnfl='$rnfl' WHERE id=1") 
or die(mysql_error());  
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rn WHERE id=1") 
or die(mysql_error());  
// get the first (and hopefully only) entry from the result
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
echo $row['dait']." - "; 
printf('(%5.2d mm)', $row['rnfl']); 
?>
```

THIS IS WHAT I GET AFTER RUNNING THE UPDATE:

```
31/7/2014 - ( 13 mm)
```

what I am looking for is: -

```
31/7/2014 - (12.9 mm)
```

Comment: Use `%f` instead of `%d`.

Comment: stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions; use MySQLi or PDO instead. Also, when you debug, remove those error-suppressing `@`

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_` function is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you're trying to store a float (`12.9`) in an `INT` type column - integer. Ints do not support decimal places. So basically your question boils down to "I'm bought a banana at the store. Why isn't it an apple?"

Change `rnfl`'s type to `float` or something like `decimal(10,2)` if you want to get that `.9` back again.

Comment: Sorry Marc B your suggestion didn't work for me.  Any other suggestions to try?

Comment: There's also the `%f` comment above. even if you do change the DB to be a float, you're still telling mysql to printf() it as an int (`%d`) instead of a float (`%f`).

Answer (score 1):

You put the type of `rnfl` field as `int` - the data will be rounded when you insert them.

Just change the type to `float` or, if you're dealing with money, `decimal(10,2)`.

Comment: Sorry rcmachado your suggestion didn't work.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: This comment got it :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25130930/php-mysql-print-decimal-number/25130968?noredirect=1#comment39133083_25130949